# AngularJS Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem with AngularJS 1.6, error message say:

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined

I know that is something with my testService, please help to find problem

**./app.js**

```
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import Components from './components/components';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';
import { ApiConstant } from './constants';
import { TestService } from './services';

angular.module('myApp', [
    uiRouter,
    Components
  ])
  .component('testPage', TestComponent)
  .service('TestService', TestService)
  .constant('ApiConstant', ApiConstant)
  .config(($stateProvider) => {
    'ngInject';
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '',
        template: '<test-page></test-page>'
      });
  });
```

**./services/test.service.js**

```
export const TestService = (ApiConstant) => {
  'ngInject';

  this.test = function() {
    console.log(ApiConstant);
    return ApiConstant;
  };
};
```

**./services/index.js**

```
export * from './test.service';
```

**./constants/api.js**

```
export const ApiConstant = {
  url: 'test'
};
```

**./constants/index.js**

```
export * from './api.constant';
```

**./components/test.component.js**

```
import template from './test.component.html';
import controller from './test.controller';

export const TestComponent = {
  template,
  controller
};
```

**./components/test.controller.js**

```
export default function TestController($scope, ApiConstant, TestService) {
  'ngInject';
  console.log(ApiConstant.url);
  console.log(TestService.test());
}
```

So ApiConstant works fine, but TestService generate error, when I will remove TestService from controller then its work fine, what can it be?

Comment: Probably related to your service being an arrow function while also using `this`

Comment: changed to export default function TestService(ApiConstant) but not working

Comment: Hmm can you create a live example?

Answer (score 0):

Module dependencies should be strings:

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> angular.module('myApp', [
>     uiRouter,
>     Components
>   ])
> ```

Should be:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'uiRouter',
    'Components'
  ])
```